# Accessing Private function using virtual function

Tags: c++, oop, virtual-functions, private-members

How to avoid The private function calling indirectly using base class virtual function.

```
class baseclass{
public:
    virtual void printmynumber() = 0;
};

class derivedclass : public baseclass
{
private:
    int m_mynumber;
    void printmynumber()
    {
        cout << m_mynumber << endl; 
    }
public:
    derivedclass(int n)
    {
       m_mynumber = n;
    }
};


void main()
{
    baseclass *bObj = new derivedclass(10);
    bObj->printmynumber();
    delete bObj;
}
```

How to avoid the calling of private function?

Comment: That makes no sense to me. Why would want to disable calling of the inherited virtual function? What's the use-case for that?

Comment: reason why/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610936/why-can-i-access-a-derived-private-member-function-via-a-base-class-pointer-to-a

Comment: Some code i seen in my project which is violating the basic oops concept rules.

Comment: If you remove the function or change its name, then it cannot be called.

Comment: @NathanOliver Any way to avoid in cpp

Comment: @Nagappa Not with keeping the function signature the same or by keeping the function public in the base class.

Comment: @NathanOliver The base class function is pure virtual. without defining that function i cannot use other function.

Comment: You can inherit privately: `class derivedclass : baseclass`, this way a derived instance won't be base and thus the method wouldn't be pubicly callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see to prevent it without modifying the base class, is to add another inheritance-layer between  between the original base-class and the final derived class. In that middle class you make the function private or deleted. And then you use a pointer to that middle class as the base pointer.

Something like

```
class baseclass
{
public:
    virtual void printmynumber() = 0;
};

struct middleclass : public baseclass
{
    void printmynumber() = delete;
};

class derivedclass : public middleclass
{
private:
    int m_mynumber;
    void printmynumber()
    {
        cout << m_mynumber << endl; 
    }
public:
    derivedclass(int n)
    {
       m_mynumber = n;
    }
};


void main()
{
    // Here use the middleclass instead of the baseclass
    middleclass *bObj = new derivedclass(10);

    // printmynumber is deleted in the middleclass and can't be called
    // This will result in a build error
    bObj->printmynumber();

    delete bObj;
}
```

This of course requires modifications of all places where the original base class is used, but it won't need modifications to the base class itself. So it's a trade-off.

Comment: Using GCC 4.8 in eclipse and i wont this it will support c++ 11 concept to delete the funtion. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Nagappa I don't know about deleted functions, but GCC 4.8 do have some C++11 functionality. Try building with `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x`).

Comment: @Nagappa The Language dialect options can be found at Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings-> GCC C++ Compiler->Dialect in recent versions (going back a few years) of Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.

`void printmynumber()` is part of the public API of `baseclass`, hence of `derivedclass`. If you wished `derivedclass::printmynumber()` not to be public, maybe `derivedclass` shouldn't inherit from `baseclass`.

As suggested in the comments, this is a violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): the [L in SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

Comment: [Obligatorily link to Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

Comment: Without doing any changes in base class can i avoid such case?

Comment: @Nagappa ... No.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with inheritance.   Given a pointer to `baseclass`, the compiler only knows it has a `public` `virtual` function, so allows calling the function accordingly.

The derived class has elected to inherit from the base class, and has implemented a function with different access.  But none of that is visible, given only a pointer to the base.

There is nothing preventing `derivedclass::printmynumber()` from being implemented to do nothing - which means if code calls it, there will be no observable effect (assuming absence of an expected effect is tolerable).

The real solution is to fix your design, not to try to work around deficiencies in it.  Don't inherit `derivedclass` from `baseclass`.   That way, no member function of `derivedclass` can be called at all, given only a pointer to `baseclass`, since the types are not related  (passing a `derivedclass *` to a function expecting a `baseclass *` will normally be diagnosed as an error).

BTW:  `main()` returns `int`, not `void`.   Some compilers support `void main()` as a non-standard extension (and the documentation for some of those compilers falsely describes such a thing as standard) but it is better avoided.

Comment: Using an eclipse with gcc 4.8 as it allows void main()

Comment: @Nagappa Just because a specific compiler allows it doesn't mean it's correct. [The `main` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) is required to return an `int` by the C++ specification.

Comment: @Nagappa if you dig into Eclipse's project properties (Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings-> GCC C++ Compiler->Warnings) you'll find a dialog box that configures the compiler to emit more diagnostic information. Turn on *Pedantic* to see warning when you use extensions that are not part of Standard C++. While you are there, consider also turning on *All Warnings* and *Extra Warnings*. Compiler warnings are the first line of defense against logic errors, so the more work the compiler does for you, the less debugging you'll probably have to do later.

Comment: The difference between `int main()` and `void main()` is that the standard requires the first (otherwise an implementation cannot claim to comply with the standard) and does not require (or disallow) supporting the second.   Practically, therefore, all real-world compilers support `int main()`, but not all support `void main()`.